# Intervals and quantiles for binomial proportion $\hat p$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question in Statistics.

q1: **Suppose a random sample of size n=1000 is obtained from a population
with probability of success $p=0.25.$**

- Find the value $a$ such that $P(\hat p ≤ a) = 0.05.$
- Find the value $c$ such that $P(0.25 − c ≤ \hat p ≤ 0.25 + c) = 0.99.$
- Find the quartiles of the distribution of $\hat p.$

Now Since I am given the $n$ and $p,$ I tried to do $X \sim B(n = 1000, p = 0.25).$ To find the $\hat p$ value, I divided $X/n$ which turned out to be 0.00025 (0.25/1000). Now If I do that then I get $P(0.00025 ≤ a) = 0.05.$

That is all I could think off. Idk how to do the rest and Idek If what I did so far is right or wrong.

Can someone please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you supposed to use software, or use a normal approximation and printed normal tables? If norm approx, start by finding mean and SD of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p = 0.25).$ If software, is R statistical software OK, or some other kind?

Comment: Are you still there? I have elaborated on the first part and given what I believe to be useful hints for the other two parts. Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(1000, .25).$ Then $P(X \le 228) = .05$ from R software:

```
qbinom(.05, 1000,.25)
## 228
```

Then $$.05 = P(X \le 228) = P(\hat p = X/n = 220/1000 = 0.228)$$
gives the answer in terms of $\hat p.$

You can compute this using normal tables as follows: $\mu =E(\hat p) = E(X/n) = np/n = p = 0.25$ and one can show $\sigma = SD(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} = 0.013693060.$ 
And $\hat p \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = .25, \sigma=.0137).$

[Earlier: You should also be able to get this answer (or very close) using normal tables.
Try to show some progress and answer questions in my Comment. I'll try to check back in 8 or 9 hrs. to see if you or someone else has shown something more.]

Added later: Then, for $\hat p:$
$$.05 = P(\hat p \le a) = P\left(\frac{\hat p - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{a-0.25}{.0137}\right) \approx P\left(Z \le \frac{a-0.25}{.0137}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal and from normal tables $\frac{a-0.25}{.0137} = -1.645,$ so $a = 0.227.$ Within the accuracy allowed by printed tables,
that may be as close to the exact 0.228 as you can get.

For the second part, use symmetry: $P(.25 - c \le \hat p \le .25 + c) = .99$ implies
that $P(\hat p \le .25 - c) = (1-.99)/2 = .005.$ Then use the normal
approximation as in the first part.

An exact solution is based on the following R computations:

```
 qbinom(.005, 1000, .25)
 ## 215
 diff(pbinom(c(215,286), 1000, .25))
 ## 0.9904334
```

For the last part, notice that the first, second, and third quartiles of
the standard normal distribution are $Q_1 = -.6745, \text{Median} = 0,$
and $Q_3 = .6745,$ from printed standard normal CDF tables. In R:

```
qnorm(c(.25,.50,.75))
## -0.6744898  0.0000000  0.6744898
```

Here is a plot of the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(1000, .25)$ along with the
density curve (blue) of the 'best-fitting' normal density. This is for $X$;
for $\hat p$, divide the numbers on the horizontal axis by 1000.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how u found the a value using the Z Table. Like we are only given a - 0.25/ 0.013 and u said a = -1.6. how did u use the table to find it. Please and Thank you.

Comment: I found $z$ such that $P(Z \le z) = 0.05$ to be $-1.645.$ My table has positive and negative $z$'s so I found the values in the body of the table nearest $0.05$ with $z = -1.64$ and $z = -1.65$ in the margins. Interpolated to get $-1.645.$ Also, bottom row of t-table (usually labeled $\infty$ for degrees of freedom) is actually standard normal. It shows cutoff for top 5% is +1.645 exactly, so mirror image must be -1.645. // But urge you to get R for free `www.r-project.org` and learn how to use `qnorm` to substitute for such 'backwards' use of normal tables.

Comment: Hope you can follow parts of what I did and compare with text or notes. Keep at it and it will start to make sense. I have taught this stuff for years and take my word for it you aren't the first person to puzzle over this kind of problems.

Comment: THANK YOOOOUUUUUUUUU SO MUCHHHHHHHH